# How to get firebase project region value to be used in firebase cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created 2 projects in two different locations. say us-central1 and asia-northeast1.
Now for these two different projects I wants to deploy the cloud functions in their respective regions.

```
const function_location = 'asia-northeast1';// I want a region of the project selected through npm 
exports.AddWebLogs = functions.region(function_location).firestore.document(............
```

How can I get the project region value either in environment variables or somewhere in process.env so that I can use it to set that region in cloud function.

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY             = xyz
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN         = xyz
REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL        = xyz
REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID          = xyz
REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET      = xyz
REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID = xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you have two projects: `Project A` is located in `us-central1` and `Project B` is located in `asia-northeast1`. You would like to know their respective regions and store this in an environment variable that you can use later on when deploying your Cloud Function.

> **To [see what your default region and zone settings are in your project](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region#looking_up_the_default_zone_or_region), you can use the cloud command-line tool:**

`gcloud compute project-info describe --project [PROJECT_ID]`

> **To [set a variable using the gcloud command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#setting_environment_variables), use the --set-env-vars flag at deploy time:**

`gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --set-env-vars myRegion=region`

> **You can [access your environment variable at runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#accessing_environment_variables_at_runtime). At runtime, environment variables are accessible via the process.env property in Node.js:**

```
gcloud functions deploy envVar --runtime nodejs10 --set-env-vars myRegion=region --trigger-http
```

> **Then, you can use:**

```
exports.envVar = (req, res) => {
  // Sends 'region' as response
  res.send(process.env.myRegion);
};
```

Hope this helps.